# healthcareai package - error with trained_model.make_factors in example_classification_2.py

Tags: python-3.x

I installed healthcareai from the instructions at the readthedocs[URL](https://healthcareai-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/getting_started/)

```
pip install https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai- 
py/zipball/master
```

After successfully running [example_classification_1.py](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-py/blob/master/example_classification_1.py), I attempted to run [example_classification_2.py](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-py/blob/master/example_classification_2.py).  However, on example_classification_2.py, the code errored out at line 62:

```
factors = trained_model.make_factors(prediction_dataframe, 
number_top_features=3)
```

The error in the console was:

File "/home/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/healthcareai/common/top_factors.py", line 55, in top_k_features
    results = list(step2.values[:, :k])

IndexError: too many indices for array

I went back and looked at the documentation for "[Choosing a Prediction Output](https://healthcareai-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/prediction_types/)" and it indicated the code should be run without the "number_top_features" option in the list:

```
factors = trained_model.make_factors(prediction_dataframe)
```

I did that, but it still threw an error.

Please advise.  Thanks.